# .htaccess redirect mainpage only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect the main page only using htaccess as i've other redirects in the other folders.

I've tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
Rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/home/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

but it redirects the entire site and causes the rest of the redirects in the proceeding directories to not work.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule `^(.*)$` means that any URL is redirected to `http://www.test.com/home/$1` ; I think you just want to redirect `/home/*` and not the other directories, is it that ?
In that case, I think you simply need to change your rule to `/home` and not `.*`

Otherwise please give us some more information, 'cause it would mean I didn't understand your problem

Comment: My new site's main page is at http://www.test.com/home/ and the old main page is at example.com. Basically, i want to redirect just the old main page to the new main page and not the other pages. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Then you need to change the `^(.*)$` to `^$`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^expertshouse\.se?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(|/|/index.php)$ http://expertshouse.wix.com/home/ [R=301,L]
```